# VBA For each cell in

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet with data in columns A to H. Some cells in column A and B have no values or are empty, but there are values in that rows other columns that is C to H. Now I have this code to do this. loop through each empty cell in B and put in the values. that is my code will fill down till the last non empty cell in B. but I get an error.

```
Sub filldownemptyAB()     
 Dim cel As Range, rng As Long
rng = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

For Each cel In rng.Cells
 With ActiveCell
 .Offset(, 0).Formula = "=year(today())"
.Offset(, -1).Value = "Actual"
End With
Next cel
  End Sub
```

the error is at this line

```
 For each cel in rng
```

Comment: A Long is not a collection of Ranges. That's why.

Comment: And try to avoid implicit activesheet references. Rather than Cells() have Worksheets(myWorksheetName).Cells()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you're looking for this:

(I edited a few times to simplify things a bit and to scan column `B` instead of column `A`)

```
Sub FillDownEmptyAB()
Dim c, lr
lr = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.CountLarge
For Each c In Range("B1:B" & lr)
    If c.Value = "" Then
        c.Offset(,-1).Value = "Actual"
        c.Formula = "=YEAR(TODAY())"
    End If
Next c
End Sub
```

Input:

[image: Input]

Output:

[image: Output]

Answer (score 2):

A `Long` is not a collection of `Ranges`.

I think you are trying to do something like this:

```
Sub filldownemptyAB()     
  Dim cel As Range
  Dim lastRow As Long
  lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

  Dim rng as Range
  Set rng = Range("B" & lastRow)

  For Each cel In rng
    With cel
      .Offset(, 0).Formula = "=year(today())"
      .Offset(, -1).Value = "Actual"
    End With
  Next cel
End Sub
```

But it's hard to tell.

Comment: The code works like a previous one I had but it only fills just one empty column A and B and doesn't loop.

Comment: @braX bro, this code is only going to "loop" through one cell. You want to do `Set rng = Range("B1:B" & lastRow)` That's not really what needs to be done at all though as far as I can tell.

Comment: Feel free to edit it if you want, I don't mind.. I don't usually do things that way. It was more just to show him that he was defining his variables wrong.

Comment: @braX, I think he wants to "loop through each empty cell in Column B and put the date in all empty cells.  The code should be If cel="" Then